# Is there a better way to perform calculations on consecutive column vectors in a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to perform some calculations on consecutive columns in a 2D array, for simplicity's sake, let's say substruction.

I currently do this in the following way:

```
c = np.array([(a[i, j + 1] - a[i, j]) for j in range(a.shape[1] - 1) for i in range(a.shape[0])]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] - 1)
```

But I suspect there must be a better way using NumPy's vector operations without iteration over 2 values and a reshape.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think that what you wrote achieves what you try to achieve.
I ran:

```
>>> a
array([[4, 6, 1, 1, 4],
       [7, 1, 7, 0, 6],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 6, 3, 2, 8]])
>>> c = np.array([(a[i, j + 1] - a[i, j]) for j in range(a.shape[1] - 1) for i in range(a.shape[0])])
>>> c
array([ 2, -6, -2,  6, -5,  6,  0, -3,  0, -7,  1, -1,  3,  6,  1,  6])
>>> c = np.array([(a[i, j + 1] - a[i, j]) for j in range(a.shape[1] - 1) for i in range(a.shape[0])]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] - 1)
>>> c
array([[ 2, -6, -2,  6],
       [-5,  6,  0, -3],
       [ 0, -7,  1, -1],
       [ 3,  6,  1,  6]])
```

The function `np.diff` receives a vector and returns it's differences array, so:

```
>>> np.diff([1, 2, 3, 5])
array([1, 1, 2])
```

But in numpy most functions can handle np.arrays and not just scalars. For this reason, a good key word to know is `axis`. When passing axis=0 or axis=1 the function will perform like the original one, but on a higher dimension. So instead of subtracting two numbers, it will subtract two vectors. axis=0 and axis=1 will give subtraction of rows and columns (respectively).

**Final Answer**:

So the final answer is: `np.diff(a, axis=1)`.

**Example:**

```
>>> a
array([[4, 6, 1, 1, 4],
       [7, 1, 7, 0, 6],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 6, 3, 2, 8]])
>>> np.diff(a, axis=1)
array([[ 2, -5,  0,  3],
       [-6,  6, -7,  6],
       [-2,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 6, -3, -1,  6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the order of loops in the question differs from what would seem to do the obvious thing.  I am going to guess here that you meant to have the `i` and `j` loops the other way round.

Given an example:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4) ** 2
```

i.e.

```
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36, 49]])
```

Swapping the order of loops gives:

```
c = np.array([(a[i, j + 1] - a[i, j]) for i in range(a.shape[0]) for j in range(a.shape[1] - 1)]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] - 1)
```

i.e.

```
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 9, 11, 13]])
```

So now proceeding to answer the question on that basis, you can do this simply using:

```
a[:,1:] - a[:,:-1]
```

Here, `a[:,1:]` is the array without the first column, `a[:,:-1]` is the array without the last column, and then the element-by-element difference between the two is calculated.

Replace `-` with whatever other operator you want. Your question implies that subtraction is just an example, but other operators (e.g. `*` or whatever) will also similarly output element-by-element results.

Your actual operation does not have to be a single basic operation; provided that it is some combination of basic operations, then you ought to be able to operate on these two subarrays in the same way that you would operate on scalars.

For example, if you have:

```
def mycalc(right, left):
    return 2 * right + left
```

then

```
mycalc(a[:,1:], a[:,:-1])
```

gives:

```
array([[  2,   9,  22],
       [ 66,  97, 134]])
```

which is the same as you get when calling `mycalc` in place of just doing a subtraction in the original example:

```
np.array([mycalc(a[i, j + 1], a[i, j]) for i in range(a.shape[0]) for j in range(a.shape[1] - 1)]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] - 1)
```